# How to dilate a contour by a specific number of pixels (without iterating over every pixel)?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am writing a Python script that converts an image into G-Code for a CNC machine. The CNC machine uses a bit cylindrical shaped bit that is 0.250 inches in diameter. My script finds the contours in the image, and then converts the coordinates from the contours into directions for the machine.

This works great, except that shape that is carved is 0.125" smaller than the designed part. The center of the bit traces directly over the contour, so the resulting shapes are too small by half the diameter of the bit.

**I want to dilate every contour by *x* pixels.** I want to make an output image where every pixel that is white in the source image is also white in the output image, but also, every pixel that is within *x* pixels of a white pixel in the input image should be white in the output image.

This is my source image:

[image: source image]

Dilating the contour using `cv2.dilate()` does not produce the results that I am looking for because it tends to make round edges square.

```
img = cv2.dilate(img, (15,15), 5)
```

[image: dilated using cv2.dilate]

I have tried iterating through the image, pixel by pixel, and then testing the distance to the contours using `cv2.pointPolygontest(contour, (x,y), True)`. This works but this hack is very slow.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def erode_contours_by_cutter_size(img, contours, cutter_size):
    # Create an output image
    outputImage = np.zeros_like(img)
    # Iterate through every pixel in the image
    for x in range(img.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img.shape[1]):
            # Check if the pixel is black
            if img[y,x] != 255:
                # Check if the distance from this pixel to a contour is smaller than the cutter size
                for contour in contours:
                    dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(contour, (x,y), True)                    
                    if abs(dist) < cutter_size:
                        outputImage[y,x] = 255
    return outputImage

img = 255-cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/t2.png',0)
img = cv2.resize(img, (234,234))
cutter_size = 50
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = erode_contours_by_cutter_size(img, contours, cutter_size)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the outputImage:

[image: output image from slow dilation method]

Comment: try distanceTransform followed by thresholding

Comment: Have you tried dilating with a [elliptical shaped kernel (`cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE`)](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element)?

Comment: Supporting nathancy's idea here, give it try! But, also another question: Which OpenCV version do you use, that `img = cv2.dilate(img, 15, 5)` works? Second parameter is the dilation kernel (structuring element) by default. I checked docs on OpenCV 4.x, 3.4.x, and 2.4.x and none of them seems to allow that code.

Comment: @HansHirse I am using OpenCV version '4.1.1', sorry there was an error in that line of code. I fixed it in an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the the cleanest solution, but it's easy and will work with all shapes. With a little extra work you can use it for cutouts inside the template as well. So it might be enough your for needs.

Find the contours, draw a white line on them 2x the size of the bit. Now use the inverted version of the impute image as a mask to leave only the routing path - as in your output image. Instead, you can also combine the images the create a larger white shape (as is stated in your question).

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

bitsize = 100
# load image
img = cv2.imread('PluT1.png',0)
# create empty image
res = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
# find countours. use a more complex CHAIN_APPROX if SIMPLE is not enough 
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contour
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(res,[cnt],0,(255),bitsize)

#invert input image to create mask
img_inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
# apply mask to get routing path
path = cv2.bitwise_and(res,res, mask=img_inverted)
# join drawn contour and input image to get solid
solid = cv2.bitwise_or(img,res)
# show images
cv2.imshow('Input',img)
cv2.imshow('Path',path)
cv2.imshow('Solid',solid)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```